# Django filter objects before deadline

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a list of jobs. I want to display only the jobs whose deadline of application has not been crossed yet compared to today's date.

in my model.py, I have a model for Job. It has a field called job_deadline which is a DateField.

How do I get all the jobs which are active?

It should be something like Jobs.objects.filter(job_deadline > date.today()). But this does not work

Comment: try using `from django.utils import timezone` then in your query something like `job_deadline__gt=timezone.now()` See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#gt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.filter()` can only take arguments (`=`) not expressions (`==`, `>`, `<=`...), so there are suffixes like __gt to indicate greater than:

`Jobs.objects.filter(job_deadline__gt = date.today())`